# Batch update using EntityFramework.Extended

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-extended

I am trying to use batch update using Entity framework extended but i am unsure how to do this.

So far this the following code that i have:

```
List<Guid> listIds = new List<Guid>();


listIds = listIds.Union(hem.ProductList.Where(x => x.CustListID == custListID).ToList().Select(y => y.OrderListID)).ToList();
```

with above query it return 1000 Order lists.

So what I am trying to achieve:
update the custListID where OrderListID in listIds above

Now I am trying using the Entity Framework extended.

```
using (var db = new DBContextEntities())
{
    var rowUpdates = db.ProductList.Update(x => x.OrderListID in listIds, x => new ProductList { CustListID = custListID});
}
```

Please advise how I can achieve this.

Comment: x => x.OrderListID in listIds is not correct syntax. Is there any way to do this? . 'in' is not correct syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for this syntax:

```
db.ProductList.Update(x => listIds.Contains(x.OrderListID),
                           x => new ProductList { CustListID = custListID });
```

`Contains` is translated to a SQL `IN` statement.